Help proving this equations from a book
I am reading an Electronic Design book, and two equations should yield a third equation in a specific section. (There is no procedure in the book, so I take this as an opportunity to prove where these equations come from and also to try to acquire a deeper level of knowledge)
(1)-->$v_o = V_o + A_0 \left( V_{ID} - V_{OS}  \right)$
(2)-->$V_{ID} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}{ \left( {\frac{\alpha_j}{\beta}x_j} \right)-{\beta v_o}} $
The solution I should arrive by replacing $V_{ID}$ from (2) in (1) is:

However, I cannot find where the $\beta$ term on the numerator inside the summation term comes from. I've arrived at almost the same solution, but this term looks like this:
$$
\frac{A_0}{1+\beta A_0} \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\left({\frac{\alpha_j}{\beta}x_j}\right) }
$$
My procedure:

Substitute (2) into (1):

$$
v_o = V_o + A_0 \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\left({\frac{\alpha_j}{\beta}x_j}\right) - A_0 \cdot \beta v_o - A_0 \cdot V_{OS}}
$$

Rearrange the equation:

$$
(1 + A_0 \cdot \beta) \cdot v_o = V_o + A_0 \sum_{j=1}^{n}{ \left({\frac{\alpha_j}{\beta}x_j}\right) - A_0 \cdot V_{OS} }
$$

Solve for $v_o$:

$$
v_o =
\frac{A_0}{1 + A_0 \cdot \beta} \sum_{j=1}^{n}{\left({\frac{\alpha_j}{\beta}x_j} \right)} 
+ \frac{V_o}{1 + A_0 \cdot \beta} 
- \frac{A_0 \cdot V_{OS}}{1 + A_0 \cdot \beta}
$$
So, I am left wondering if the book is wrong or if I am doing something wrong. (I am more inclined to the latter. Also, because this equation is used in the following chapters, so truly I don't believe that it is wrong)
So please let me know what you think; I want to find out where I am making mistakes.

Cant see anything wrong with what you did.

The book evidently has an error. It could be that the $\beta$ in the numerator is incorrect, or it could be that there should be an additional $\beta$ in equation (2).
